# Swift Compile Error: does not conform to protocol

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am using the Cocoapod Money (version 2.0.1).  When I try to build it, I get the error "Type _Decimal does not conform to protocol 'Numeric'"  Any ideas as to how to fix it?

I've already tried removing and reinstalling the cocoapod.

Thanks,

Comment: Please post the code that causes the compiler error.

Comment: The code is in the Decimal.swift for the pod: https://github.com/danthorpe/Money/blob/development/Sources/Decimal.swift#L37

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you’re using a Numeric number while the pod wants an decimal number.  Just try to cast your numeric in decimal and it should work.

Comment: It's not in my code...the Pod itself is throwing an error: https://github.com/danthorpe/Money/blob/development/Sources/Decimal.swift#L37

Answer (score 0):

According to the pod's `.swift-version` it is written in Swift 3. My guess is that the build error results from a conflict in Swift versions with the current Xcode. The project is no longer maintained but according to [this issue](https://github.com/danthorpe/Money/issues/79) there is a branch which should make it buildable on Xcode 9.